# DIY device to repeatedly depress and release gas pedal on a vehicle

Tags: motors, electrical

The pedal needs to be depressed about 1/2 to 1 inch, once every three minutes.  I believe the best way to do this will be with a rotating arm of length 2 to 2 1/2 inches that has rollers on each end, rotating at 1/6 rpm.  The device needs to be powerful enough to overcome the moderate amount of tension in the pedal spring.  It will preferably plug into a standard 120-volt outlet.  It needs to be portable, so I plan to anchor it to the floor by putting a heavy weight on top of the base of its frame.

So my main question here is, where can I find an electric rotating arm of length 2 to 2 1/2 inches that's powerful enough to overcome the spring tension in the pedal?  Is it easy to find an electric motor with a 120-volt plug that one can easily attach an arm to?  Finding something that'll work for the arm, attaching rollers to it, and building a proper frame will be easy.  It's mainly just the motor that I'm unfamiliar with selecting and obtaining.

There is plenty of clearance above the pedal, so an arm of up to about 6 inches would work.

A small eccentric cam was my first thought, but rollers are easier to attach to an arm than a cam.  A piston-like device also came to mind, but that seems way more involved than a rotating arm.  Any suggestions/ideas for accomplishing my goal will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a roller cam.

Comment: The geared motor from an old electric wheelchair will be powerful enough - but will run on 24V likely.

Comment: A 12V wiper motor would do, even has limit switches for parking which could be adapted...

Comment: @SolarMike I like both your suggestions (and the other one too).  Note: the device is for while I'm asleep, so I'll need to be satisfied that it's safe/reliable.